# React todo list - Checkbox is not changing

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I started to learn React and I'm following a tutorial. I'm trying to change the checkboxes when it's clicked. I checked if handleChange function before writing the setState code and it's working. I did everything as in the tutorial but when I click to checkboxes, they are not changing. Looks like I'm missing something. Here is the code:

App.js :

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import TodoItem from "./TodoItem";
import todosData from "./todosData";

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      todos: todosData,
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(id) {
    this.setState(prevState => {
      const updatedTodos = prevState.todos.map(todo => {
        if (todo.id === id) {
          todo.completed = !todo.completed
        }
        return todo
      })
      return {
        todos: updatedTodos
      }
    })
  }

  render() {
    const todoItems = this.state.todos.map((item) => (
      <TodoItem key={item.id} item={item} handleChange={this.handleChange} />
    ));

    return (
      <div className="todo-list">
          {todoItems}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

TodoItem.js :

```
import React from "react";
import "./index.css";

function TodoItem(props) {
  return (
    <div className="todo-item">
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        checked={props.item.completed}
        onChange={() => props.handleChange(props.item.id)}
      />
      <p>{props.item.text}</p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default TodoItem;
```

todosData.js:

```
const todosData = [
    {
        id: 1,
        text: "Take out the trash",
        completed: true
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        text: "Grocery Shopping",
        completed: false        
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        text: "Clean gecko tank",
        completed: false
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        text: "Mow lawn",
        completed: true
    },
    {
        id: 5,
        text: "Catch up on Arrested Development",
        completed: false
    }
]

export default todosData
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the problem is you're mutating the callback parameter in `handleChange`, it's generally highly recommended to avoid mutating them cause they lead to unexpected behavior. I'd rewrite like below:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      todos: todosData
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(id) {
    this.setState(prevState => {
      const updatedTodos = prevState.todos.map(todo => {
        if (todo.id === id) return { ...todo, completed: !todo.completed };
        return todo;
      });
      return {
        todos: updatedTodos
      };
    });
  }

  render() {
    const todoItems = this.state.todos.map(item => (
      <TodoItem key={item.id} item={item} handleChange={this.handleChange} />
    ));

    return <div className="todo-list">{todoItems}</div>;
  }
}
```

You can check the result here: https://xd5w9.codesandbox.io/